# Exchange - get age range of items using Powershell

Tags: exchange, powershell

We are going to be implementing personal archives for Exchange in our organization.  For us to get a good grasp on how much space is needed, we need to get an idea of the age of items that we currently have.  Is it possible to have a powershell script that tells me the total size and number of items given certain date ranges of all mailboxes in all databases?

What I'd like to have is the 1) number of items, 2) total size of times (GB) - all grouped by date ranges (Less than 15 days, 15-30 days, 30-60 days, 60-90 days, more than 90).  Another possibility would be to have it also grouped by mailbox database

Answer (score 2):

For anyone coming across this page while doing a search, a much more complete solution is detailed at http://gsexdev.blogspot.com/2012/10/reporting-on-item-age-count-and-size-in.html

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! Generally we like answers on the site to be able to stand on their own - Links are great, but if that link ever breaks the answer should have enough information to still be helpful. Please consider editing your answer to include more detail. See the [FAQ](http://www.serverfault.com/faq) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

http://exchangeserverpro.com/powershell-script-create-mailbox-size-report-exchange-server-2010

Get-mailboxstatistics is the cmdlet for you .... Above is a good write up and a script to get the info you are after ....

Hope this helps

```
$date = (Get-Date).toString(‘yyyy-MM-dd’)
Get-MailboxFolderStatistics "username" | sort-object itemsinfolder -descending | ft Folder, FolderPath, ItemsInFolder, FolderSize -auto | export-csv -path $date.csv
```

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8980195/exchange-mailbox-traffic-auditing

You can also investigate message tracking logs :
http://www.simple-talk.com/content/print.aspx?article=681

Comment: It's a start, but is there a way using get-mailboxstatistics to apply a date limit (e.g: received>=xxx and received<=xxx ?

Comment: Referring to added in script: forgive my ignorance, but that looks like all it does it grabs all file info and labels the output file with the current date.  It doesn't grab data by date range